# Como fazer banner AdMob preecher toda largura?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, admob

Olá zerei os `padding` do XML e coloquei `wrap_content`, mas o banner do `AdMob` não preenche toda largura fica espaços como resolver?

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    tools:context="br.com.planetsweb.dolarhoje.Tela1"
    android:background="#e8e8e8">


    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A largura do `AdView` varia dependendo do atributo `adSize`. Você pode verificar esses tamanhos em [Anúncios de *banner*](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/banner#banner_size).

Em contrapartida, ao invés de usar `AdView` você pode substituir por [`InterstitialAd`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/InterstitialAd). Os [**Anúncios intersticiais**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/interstitial) são anúncios de tela cheia que cobrem a interface do aplicativo. Normalmente, são exibidos em pontos de transição natural no fluxo de um aplicativo, como entre atividades ou durante uma pausa entre níveis em um jogo. Quando um aplicativo exibe um intersticial, o usuário pode escolher tocar no anúncio e seguir para a página de destino ou fechá-lo e retornar ao aplicativo.

Veja como adicionar anúncios intersticiais a uma *activity*:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    Button mNewGameButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNewGameButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newgame_button);

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                requestNewInterstitial();
                beginPlayingGame();
            }
        });

        requestNewInterstitial();

        mNewGameButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                } else {
                    beginPlayingGame();
                }
            }
        });

        beginPlayingGame();
    }

    private void requestNewInterstitial() {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                  .addTestDevice("SEE_YOUR_LOGCAT_TO_GET_YOUR_DEVICE_ID")
                  .build();

        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    private void beginPlayingGame() {
        // Play for a while, then display the New Game Button
    }
}
```

Veja um exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja detalhes [na documentação](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/interstitial).

Comment: Seu link foi útil o tamanho SMART_BANNER que completa toda largura, já uso o interstitial ad.